# Is there a way to write in .resx files?

Tags: asp.net, localization, resources

I found about ReasourceWriter but when i write in a .resx file i get some artifacts, is there an alternative?

resx file:

```
ÎĘďľ‘lSystem.Resources.ResourceReader, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089#System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSetPADPADP®mYĹenTest123
```

oh and why can't i find ResXResourceReader in my namespace in asp.net?

Comment: I don't think you can write to resource file if they are embedded in you library. What does it mean 'You get some artifacts'? Did you try  this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ekyft91f(v=vs.90).aspx`)

Comment: I fixed it, i implemented ResXResourceReader, but now i only get 1 item in my Resx. file, here is the code:  `ResXResourceWriter resourceWriter = new ResXResourceWriter("C:\\Resource1.resx");
            for(int i=0;i<item.Count();i++)
            {
                if(item[i].Key.LangId == "en")
                    resourceWriter.AddResource(item[i].Key.LangId, item[i].Text);
               
            }`